# animate div using angularjs animate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am using angularJs 1.2+ and angular ui router.
I have a route that contains div. When entering to that route, a div showed up. I would like to add an animation to that div for enter and leave but I don't know how to do it.
I don't know if I should create a directive that uses $animate or use a built in directive of angular. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a FAQ:

- [How to: Animate ui-view with ng-animate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate)

And also the related [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview).

As explained in **[Developer Guide / Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)**,

#### How they work:

> Animations in AngularJS are completely based on CSS classes. As long as you have a CSS class attached to a HTML element within your website, you can apply animations to it...

So, this way we can create some CSS definitions related to our `ui-view` element *(class or attribute as used in the plunker)* and ngAnimation injected classes: `.ng-enter`, `.ng-leave`..

A snippet from the FAQ related [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview)

```
[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
    ...
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    ...
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  ...
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  ...
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1; 
  ...
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to animate ui-view, I want to animate a dic inside ui-view.

Comment: But is not it the same? we know, that the parent element will get some CSS - because of the `ui-router` and `animation`. So, the DIRECTIVE element could use these parent classes to define its own transitions: `.parent.ng-enter .myDirClass` - and you have what you need! ;) ;)

Comment: Not exactly because this means that I have to add transition also to .parent.ng-enter .myDirClass and this makes mess.

Comment: Ok, I respect that this won't suite to your needs. Just wanted to show a way, which seems to me to be a feasible. Good luck with awesome `ui-router` anyhow ...;)

Comment: Another thing, my [ui-view] is not an element. Therefore putting transition on it will not work.

Comment: Well, what do you mean? there always will be an HTML element, representing the view anchor. And it does not matter if it is `<div ui-view />` or `<ui-view>` ... both can have some class. Just, please, observe the plunker I appended to my answer....

Comment: Add classes and styles to '<ui-view></ui-view>' element will do nothing because the browser doesn't draw them. Such an element can't have absolute position for example. Try for yourself.

Comment: @Naor ;) then change it;) It si your code, is not it? And that's why we can use more ways... including `<div ui-view ..` anyhow, my suggested solution is working and I do accept that you do not like it...good luck

Comment: At the end I did transition on the ui-view element and not on the inner div. Your answer was the most related.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the animation in CSS and have `ngAnimate` apply and remove the appropriate classes.

Or here is a nice Angular Lib that I use with predefined animations: https://github.com/Hendrixer/ng-Fx

Read the directions carefully, you need the TweenMax.js library.

Comment: Do you have an example for use with that ngAnimate directive? Keep in mind, I am using Angular 1.2 + .

Comment: All possible animations with the ng-fx have examples here: http://hendrixer.github.io/